# What should I do if I type my password in the address bar, or type password in google search?

Tags: passwords, google, passphrase, caching

When someone accidentally types his or her password in one of the following three locations and presses enter, what should they do?

1. username text box
2. address bar
3. Google search

What do you suggest, for example, a checklist, or instruction note?

And what might happen to him?

Comment: Change your password.  I suggest changing it to `www.google.com` so you don't have this problem again.

Comment: many of users before loading the page, type their usernames or passwords. after loading pages cursor move to username textbox and their password visible to others. always saved this password in that text box. and increases security Risks for them. and they forget to clean cache and anything else related to place that passwords saved!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you accidentally disclose your password -- either through typing it into the address bar, or in any other way -- it's best to **change it**.

There's no need for any complicated checklist.  Simply change that password, everywhere that you used that particular password.  This will protect you.

Is it absolutely necessary to change your password if you typed it into the address bar?  Perhaps not -- in practice, the risk is probably modest.  Then again, why take a chance?  If you type it into the address bar, it may be disclosed in cleartext over the network. For instance, if you are currently connected using open Wifi, anyone within range of the network who is eavesdropping could capture your password.  Also, your password could potentially be captured in various logs.  So, at that point, rather than taking a gamble, the safest thing to do is to immediately change your password.  If you do that, you'll probably be fine.

Comment: structure of Password was caught?

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi, sorry, I couldn't make sense of that comment; perhaps you would like to try again?  It might help to use complete sentences.

Comment: Even if I change my password, but the Structure of my password was revealed and hackers could guess 100 other passwords of mine in the internet or bank or mobile passwords.

Comment: your passwords should not have such structure. If other passwords are easily derived from a known password, you should change all of them.

Comment: Then change all passwords with that structure. If you think it's compromised => Change it

Comment: You shouldn't be re-using (or even remembering) passwords for most things anyway. That's what we have password managers like [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) for. In reality you should never really need to remember more than 4 passwords - your system encryption password, your OS login password, your password manager password, and your email account password (allows recovery of most passwords in the case of losing your password database). Everything else goes in your password manager, and is unique + properly random.

Comment: Whether a password typed in an address bar would be sent over the network depends on what your password is and/or how the browser processes text input in the address bar.  Some browsers check that whatever you type in the address bar is a valid URL, and issue an error message if not.  For these browsers it may be perfectly safe to type your password there.  Other browsers may try to rewrite your password as a domain (e.g., by appending ".com") and then try to connect to the site, or they may run a web search on the password.  In these cases you should consider your password compromised.

Answer (score 3):

*(Originally from [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/231088/70406)), this is a more detailed answer regarding pasting a password into the...*

### Address bar

In this scenario, the ***name resolution*** is your worst enemy, as it leaks the password in multiple ways. Your password will leak to multiple DNS servers and through the local network – mostly in plain text, even if you are using encrypted connection to your DNS resolver.

- DNS *resolvers* will not handle the query just within themselves: they will start asking it from the *authoritative* name servers, starting from the root servers, or from a *forwarder* that does it for them.
- As this is not a real working domain name, it will be also queried using

  - *Multicast DNS* (mDNS, [RFC 6762](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762)) and
  - *Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution* (LLMNR, [RFC 4795](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4795)).
- Both mDNS and LLMNR are using *IP multicasting*.

  - By default, ethernet switches will flood these requests to every port, as they won't see the *multicast MAC addresses* beginning with `01:00:5e` as a source address on any ethernet frame.
  - Some switches can limit this using *IGMP snooping*, but it's still possible for anyone to join these multicast groups to get these IP multicast transmissions.

In addition, the password will leak to your **search provider** with most modern browsers after the name resolutions fails. Some browsers may also start sending out contents in the address bar even *before* you have pressed the enter, as explained in an [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/163390/70406) for "*Does accidentally pasting password into browser URL field send it over the network?*".

**TL;DR: Change your password.**

---

In this example, `testp4ssw0rd` is typed into the address bar of Google Chrome on Windows 10.

[image: Packet capture from Wireshark]

- The computer `192.0.2.100` has local domain (configured through DHCP) `example.com` and,  as a common bad practice, `example.local`. The `192.0.2.254` is a router that also acts as a DNS resolver.

  - With `example.com`, the resolver, any MITM and the `ns1.example.com` will know the `testp4ssw0rd`.
  - With `example.local`, the the NXDOMAIN reply comes from a root server.
- The MDNS (`5353/udp`) query `testp4ssw0rd.local` to `224.0.0.251` is an IP multicast query message with MAC address `01:00:5E:00:00:FB`. It asks the host having that name to identify itself.
- Likewise, LLMNR (`5355/udp`) query `testp4ssw0rd` to `244.0.0.252` is an IP multicast query message with MAC address `01:00:5E:00:00:FC`.
- As there wasn't devices with these names, you won't see mDNS/LLMNR responses.